# Web Scrape Javascript Based Tables

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the content of the tables including phone numbers but can't extract all the data.

Here's my code:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os


def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata
playerdata=""
playerdatasaved=""
soup = make_soup("https://www.camicb.org/find-a-cmca")


for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        print(data.string)
```

Comment: Did you note the error message: 'It looks like your browser does not have JavaScript enabled. Please turn on JavaScript and try again.'

Comment: The underlying content (DETAILS -- where the phone number is) is created by  Javascript, thus you need to look at using something like selenium to acquired that data.

Comment: You could scrape the underlying href tags, which has a complete record.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data if you use Selenium. Then you can click through all the pages on the website scraping data. First install Selenium.

```
sudo pip3 install selenium
```

(you will not need sudo on Windows, you may want pip not pip3)

Then get a driver https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads (Depending upon your OS you may need to specify the location of your driver)

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

# parse the page
def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    for detail in  soup.find_all('div',{'class': 'professional-details'}):
        print (detail.find('div',{'class': 'fullname'}).get_text(strip=True),\
            detail.find('div',{'class': 'phone'}).get_text(strip=True))

# request the first page.
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://www.camicb.org/find-a-cmca"
driver.get(url)

while True:
    try:
        # parse the current page.
        time.sleep(3)
        parse(driver.page_source)
        # Find the next page button and click it.
        driver.find_element_by_id('A6').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        # Couldn't find a next page button must have got to the end.
        break
driver.quit()
```

Outputs:

```
Ms. Sandy                             Aaron (602) 692-5494
Mrs. Zafera                             Aaron (425) 283-5858  (103)
Mr. Rick                             Abair 
Mr. Karmel Ahmed                            Abbas 971-0504805551
...
Ms. Kimberely Ann                            van Heel (949) 285-0111
Mr. Willem Schalk                            van Schalkwyk (617) 777-3761
Mr. Gary                             van der Laan (407) 781-5769
```